# swipeable carousel with dynamic height

Tags: meteor, carousel

I have an app in  meteor .I want to read my websites feeds in a   carousel with dynamic height . I have (read more)  button  at the bottom of each slides . witch carousel plugin is suitable for this goal?

Answer (score 0):

If your plan is for React, I'd go for `react-swipeable-views` which also supports virtualization for any number of pages left-right and pre-rendering at number of slides ahead or back.

With this library you have some listeners so you can check the hight of a slide after rendering and set the height of the slide container dynamically. Since you are on mobile, the experience should be ok if most of your articles are longer than the viewport. When you load a new slide you would call something like `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` to start at the top.

Comment: thanks . but unfortunately I don't use react in my app